# how to make horizontal spacing b/w UIfields using Autolayouts in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

In my app I have added one text field and one button on my mainview controller using Autolayouts.

Using the below code, the horizontal spacing is not applied between UItextfild and Button. What could I have done wrong?

```
  NSDictionary * views1 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(RoundTripDateTextField,RoundTripButton);

  [RoundTripBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[RoundTripDateTextField]-8-[RoundTripButton(30)]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views1]];
  [RoundTripBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[RoundTripDateTextField(30)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views1]];  
  [RoundTripBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[RoundTripButton(30)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your constraints. I have written a snippet using same constraints, just tweaked them a little:

```
UIView *RoundTripBackGround = [[UIView alloc] init];
RoundTripBackGround.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
RoundTripBackGround.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self.view addSubview:RoundTripBackGround];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[RoundTripBackGround]|"
                                                                  options:0 metrics:nil
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(RoundTripBackGround)]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(20)-[RoundTripBackGround]"
                                                                  options:0 metrics:nil
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(RoundTripBackGround)]];

UITextField *RoundTripDateTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
RoundTripDateTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
RoundTripDateTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[RoundTripBackGround addSubview:RoundTripDateTextField];

UIButton *RoundTripButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
RoundTripButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
RoundTripButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[RoundTripBackGround addSubview:RoundTripButton];

NSDictionary * views1 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(RoundTripDateTextField,RoundTripButton);

[RoundTripBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[RoundTripDateTextField]-8-[RoundTripButton(30)]|"
                                                                            options:0 metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views1]];

[RoundTripBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[RoundTripDateTextField(30)]|"
                                                                            options:0 metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views1]];

[RoundTripBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[RoundTripButton(30)]|"
                                                                            options:0 metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views1]];
```

Things to notice:

1. Use "|[view]|" instead of "|-0-[view]-0-|".
2. In the last two vertical constraint you haven't set a constraint with the boundary ("V:|-0-[RoundTripDateTextField(30)]" vs "V:|[RoundTripDateTextField(30)]|").